# Tkinter frame expand is only displaying half my window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to create a phone in tkinter and i'm using frames but the image is being cut in half. Does anyone know why?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOtEn.png

```
import tkinter as tk

def raiseframe(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

root = tk.Tk()

bgImage = tk.PhotoImage(file="Phone.gif")
WALogo = tk.PhotoImage(file="whatsappLogo.gif")
width = bgImage.width()
height = bgImage.height()

root.title("Phone")
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height))

main = tk.Frame()
whatsapp = tk.Frame()

for frame in (main, whatsapp):
    frame.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

#Mainscreen:
canvas = tk.Canvas(main, width = width, height = height, bg = "black")
canvas.create_image((width / 2, height / 2), image = bgImage)
canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
WAB = tk.Button(main, image = WALogo, command = lambda: raiseframe(whatsapp))
WAB.place(x = 35, y = 85)

raiseframe(main)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i believe you have added the picture into a frame which only takes up up to half of the screen

Comment: Thanks so much for this adding a width and height to the frames fixed the issue

Comment: Read up on [Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method) focus at the `anchor=` option. You have to use `NW`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have added the picture into a frame which only takes up up to half of the screen.
You could either:

- change the dimensions of the frame
- add the picture to root like this:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = width, height = height, bg = "black")
canvas.create_image((width / 2, height / 2), image = bgImage)
```